# Fail to access the default Quality Gate through the REST API

Tags: sonarqube

Using the python and REST API I loop over all Quality gates.

I have in total 5 Projects with 2 different Quality Gates named "Good" and "Excellent".

2 Projects using "Good" Quality gate and 3 using "Excellent" Quality Gate.
The 3 projects setup as "Excellent" are using the default Quality Gate.

- When requesting the number of projects in "Excellent" I get the answer 0!

When Changing from default to "Excellent" Quality Gate I get the correct number: 3!

I find no API for the default Quality Gate?

I find no way of discovering the name of Default Gateway?

Shouldn't the "default" be resolved to "Excellent"?

```
for gate in gates['qualitygates']:

     qualId = gate['id']
     projs = sonarH.get_search_quality_gates(qualId)
     theProjects = projs['results']

     print("Quality Gate Name: " + gate['name'] + " Count: " + str(len(theProjects)))
```

output:

```
Quality Gate Name: ST :: Excellent Quality Count: 0
Quality Gate Name: ST :: Good Quality Count: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behaviour. The web service returns the number of projects that are explicitly associated with the gate, but not the effective number of projects using it. For this reason zero is always returned for the gate marked as default.

An alternate approach is to request the Quality gate used for each project, by using the web service `api/qualitygates/get_by_project?projectKey=[the_key]`. Note that this web service is marked as "internal" so changes may be applied in future versions without keeping backward-compatibility.

Comment: Attempted to access this api but got a "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

Any other way of accessing the "default" gateway?

Comment: The web service I mentioned has been introduced in version 6.1: https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/qualitygates/get_by_project